# Is there a way to understand clusters of zeros and then remove it from numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to remove zeros from the middle of a numpy array (but not all zeros should be removed)

Removing zeros are demonstrated in multiple examples across stackoverflow, but I am still finding it hard to write a logic for my problem.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([255,255,255,255,255
,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255
,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255
,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,255,255,255,255
,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255
,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,207,0,0
,159,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255
,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255
,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255
,255,64,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,88,239,255,255,255,255,255,255,255
,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,231,88])
```

I have an array a, where there are some non-zero values and a big cluster of zeros (along with some zeros in the middle of the non-zero values). I want to remove that big cluster of zeros or find the index where that big cluster starts. Then reduce the array to the following form:

```
a1 = [255,255,255,255,255
,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255
,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255
,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,255,255,255,255
,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255
,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,207,0,0
,159,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255
,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255
,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255
,255,64]
```

and

```
a2=[88,239,255,255,255,255,255,255,255
,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,231,88]
```

Notice that the array a1, still has some zeros in it. the operation should only remove the zeros if there are a certain number of consecutive zeros in it(say 10 zeros). I can do it with loops iterating over the array, but if a simpler and faster approach can be suggested, that would be great.

Comment: Do you want it to remove them in blocks of 10? Or if there are more than 10, remove all?

Comment: @JerryM. I would like to remove if I see a block of length more than 10. So if I see only 5 zeros together, I would like to keep it. If there are more than 10, the entire block of zeros should go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any import, using a single loop :

```
def remove_clusters(my_array, cluster_value, consecutive_max=10):
    my_result = [[]]
    cluster_list = []
    for e in my_array:
        if e == cluster_value:
            cluster_list.append(e)
        else:
            if len(cluster_list) <= consecutive_max:
                my_result[-1].extend(cluster_list)
            else:
                my_result.append([])
            cluster_list = []
            my_result[-1].append(e)
    return my_result
```

I got this using `itertools.groupby`, which simplifies a little bit the code :

```
def remove_clusters(my_array, cluster_value=0, max_consecutive=10):
    from itertools import groupby
    my_result = [[]]
    for k,g in groupby(my_array):
        g = list(g)
        if k != cluster_value or len(g) <= max_consecutive:
            my_result[-1].extend(g)
        else:
            my_result.append([])
    return my_result
```

Then you can do:

```
a1, a2 = remove_clusters(a)
```

Finally, a very ugly oneliner using `functools.reduce`

```
from itertools import groupby
from functools import reduce
a1, a2 = reduce(lambda x,y: x + [[]] if not y[0] and len(y)>10 
                       else x[:-1] + [x[-1]+y], 
                map(lambda x: list(x[1]), groupby(a)), 
                [[]])
```

I would love to explain this oneliner but I already do not understand it anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. The first one is quite straight forward and I understand. The second one  is a little bit difficult to grasp (I haven't used itertools before) but it works great for me ! :)
Using the group-by function required much less looping. Is this also implemented in C/C++ like the numpys? I was wondering how this will affect the overall performance of my app. (But now it seems to work great)

Comment: [Looks like it is](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it using mostly numpy and not really any arrays (outside of list comprehensions). The basic idea is to get a list of `[(value1, count1), (value2, count2)...]` and then search that list for your required conditional.

There are a couple of things that could be improved, primarily having the check the conditions twice.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([255,255,255,255,255
,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255
,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255
,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,255,255,255,255
,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255
,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,207,0,0
,159,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255
,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255
,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255
,255,64,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,88,239,255,255,255,255,255,255,255
,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,231,88])

def remove_consecutive(thearray, num, count):

    # Find the indices where there is a *change* in value
    adiff = np.diff(a)
    indices = np.hstack((np.array([0]), np.where(adiff)[0]+1))

    # Given the indices we can find the lengths of the lists by just doing a                                                                     
    # diff on the indices. Have to append a dummy so the last value is included.                                                                 
    lengths = np.diff(indices, append=indices[-1]+1)

    # Now construct a tuple of (value, length)
    the_list = list(zip(a[indices], lengths))

    # Find the places where we need to split based on the num/count requirement.                                                                 
    index_breaks = np.array([ii for ii, (lvalue, lcount) in enumerate(the_list) if lvalue == num and lcount > count])                            

    # Split the (value,length) list based on the index_breaks
    the_list_split = np.split(the_list, index_breaks)

    # Now expand back out.
    output_list = [ np.array([lvalue for lvalue, lcount in sublist for _ in range(lcount) if not( lvalue == num and lcount > count)])            
                    for sublist in the_list_split]

    return np.array(output_list).flatten()

a1, a2 = remove_consecutive(a, 0, 10)

print(a1)
print(a2)
```

The output is:

```
[255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
 255 255 207   0   0 159 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
 255 255 255 255 255 255  64]
[ 88 239 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
 255 255 255 255 255 255 231  88]
```